# How to develop a local user login in an Android Application, is there an API or I must develop it from scratch?

Tags: android, authentication

I want to add a local login to my application so my questions:

The users will be locally stored in a database.

1- Is there an API that facilitate this task ? session manager for example ?

2- Elsewhere, if I develop my own login module, my first activity (main menu) should call a login dialog or a login activity ? How this could be made by code to prevent the use of the application. My constraint is to be able to activate or deactivate this security using the settings.

Thanks,

Comment: you can use the sqlite database to store credentials,and make custom dialog boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class to manage logins that are used for an online webservice.
For offline login, "Shared Preferences" may be enough. If you need to add a password to a local app, chances are that you want it to be secure though, so you may want to implement your own crypted database.